# Using tidyr::complete with group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Does anyone know if `tidyr::complete()` supports grouping via `group_by()`?

To be precise: I have some data frame that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(
  "ID"   = rep(1:2, each = 2),
  "Col1" = c("A", NA, "AA", NA),
  "Col2" = c("B", "C", "BB", "CC"))
```

Now i'd like to use `complete()` and `group_by()` to compute all possible combinations **per group**!

```
df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 complete(Col1, Col2)

  Error in .Call("dplyr_left_join_impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", x, y, by_x,  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

This causes an error. However, using `complete()` without grouping works but thats not what i want.

```
df %>% 
 complete(Col1, Col2)
```

Questions:

1. Have I done anything wrong, or does `complete()` simply not work with `group_by`?
2. If so, how could I do this instead (preferably without using a loop)?

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(df)[,CJ(Col1, Col2, unique=TRUE), by = ID]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it using `complete` and `group_by`, but you have to use a `do` statement:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 do(complete(., Col1, Col2, fill = list(ID = .$ID)))
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), and Cross Join (`CJ`) the `unique` elements of 'Col1' and 'Col2', grouped by 'ID'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df)[,CJ(Col1, Col2, unique=TRUE), by = ID]
#   ID V1 V2
#1:  1 NA  B
#2:  1 NA  C
#3:  1  A  B
#4:  1  A  C
#5:  2 NA BB
#6:  2 NA CC
#7:  2 AA BB
#8:  2 AA CC
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to let everyone know that with the devolopment version of `tidyr` (version 0.3.1.9000 as of 13.01.2016) all `tidyr` verbs now respect grouping so a workaround using `dplyr::do` is not necessary anymore. I will edit my answer once the version is avaiable on CRAN.